# How to simplify this factorial expression?

Tags: math, factorial, simplification

I always have trouble with factorials. Can someone walk me through simplifying this expression?

> (x+1)! - 1 + (x+1)(x+1)!

I'm trying to get it to equal to (x+2)! - 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming related question.

Comment: Hint: `(x+2)! - 1 = (x+2)(x+1)! - 1 = ((x+1) + 1)(x+1)! - 1` and just multiply that out. Fundamental fact used: `(n+1)! = (n+1) x n!`.

Comment: @andand oops sorry, I thought I posted this under the Mathematics community.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful yeah I was going to accept yours but I can't until a certain time after posting. Will accept in 2 minutes.

Comment: @heyheyheyyyyy, you used the math tag for math related programming problems.  There's an entire site, http://math.stackexchange.com/ dedicated to answering questions such as the one you posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved as :-

```
(x+1)! - 1 + (x+1)(x+1)!
= (x+1)! + (x+1)(x+1)! - 1
= (x+1)!.{1+(x+1)} - 1
= (x+1)!.{x+2} - 1
= (x+2)! - 1.    // since n!.(n+1) = (n+1)!
```

Hence proved.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I wasn't understanding how (x+1)!(x+2) would equal (x+2)!

Answer (score 2):

Note that `(x+1)! = (x+1)*x!`

```
(x+1)! - 1 + (x+1)(x+1)!
= (x+1)!((x+1)+1) - 1
= (x+1)!(x+2) - 1
= (x+2)! - 1
```